# SeLinux stops starting of nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl, centos7, selinux

Reboted nginx proxy server (centos7+nginx only, apache on another) I got error:

```
  DOMAIN systemd[1]: Starting Session 439 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-439.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
--
-- Unit session-439.scope has begun starting up.
Jun 08 06:30:02 DOMAIN CROND[16408]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/sbin/script.sh)
Jun 08 06:30:02 DOMAIN CROND[16409]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/script.pl >/dev/null)
Jun 08 06:31:31 DOMAIN sshd[16419]: Connection closed by 10.1.1.3 [preauth]
Jun 08 06:33:40 DOMAIN run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[16439]: finished 0yum-daily.cron
Jun 08 06:33:40 DOMAIN run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[16441]: starting logrotate
Jun 08 06:33:45 DOMAIN run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[16505]: finished logrotate
Jun 08 06:33:45 DOMAIN run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[16507]: starting man-db.cron
Jun 08 06:33:47 DOMAIN run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[16516]: finished man-db.cron
Jun 08 06:33:47 DOMAIN run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[16518]: starting update-ocsp
Jun 08 06:33:56 DOMAIN systemd[1]: Stopping nginx - high performance web server...
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Unit nginx.service has begun shutting down.
Jun 08 06:33:56 DOMAIN systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Jun 08 06:33:56 DOMAIN nginx[16568]: nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/client-ocsp.pem") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission den
Jun 08 06:33:56 DOMAIN nginx[16568]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jun 08 06:33:56 DOMAIN systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 08 06:33:56 DOMAIN systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- The result is failed.
```

After `restorecon -R -v /etc/nginx/ssl/` and  `restorecon -R -v /etc/nginx/ssl/*.pem`

Nginx started, today was updated ocsp what worked years before, afrer nginx restart i have got same permission denied error.

How it can solve? It's production server, little bit scare to experiment with it
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide relevant AVC denial error messages from audit log (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general solution to allowing what was previously denied.

(optional) First we disable enforcing so we can do it all at once, not rerun and add one change at a time every time it fails:

```
setenforce 0
```

Then we start nginx, use it a bit, restart it too (so we log anything shutdown related)

Then we review what we'll be allowing:

```
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

And if you are satisfied with allowing everything mentioned:

```
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M my-nginx-module
```

But if you weren't satisfied, adjust the grep to match something more specific, for example:

```
grep -E "name_connect.*nginx|nginx.*someporttype..." /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

And now we enable enforcing again, and retest.

```
setenforce 1
```

Answer (score 1):

SELinux does not expect certificates to be placed in the `/etc/nginx` directory, so if you place them there they may come up with the wrong contexts.

Store your certificates in the default directory structure under `/etc/pki/tls`. If you use Let's Encrypt, and have installed the `certbot` package, then you can also use `/etc/letsencrypt`.

Files may also have the wrong context if you `mv` them instead of `cp`. On SELinux enabled systems, always remember to copy files and then delete the original if it needs to be deleted, or use `mv -Z`.

Answer (score -6):

Personally I would just turn off SELinux. It causes a lot of trouble and complicate to set up. I admire the developers of SELinux, but this thing is terrible at the moment. :D

Comment: SELinux is quite easy. But if you never learned it, then it can seem hard. Take 10 minutes to learn how to use SELinux and you will be a better admin.

Comment: SElinux is definitely worth learning, it can easily save your job when having to deal with a security breach. Turning it off is clearly giving up an important layer of security.

Comment: Your advice is bad and you should feel bad